# How can I create a virtual or similar column in MSSQL that can be updated that simply reflects the value in another field

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a web application that connects to a legacy back end system. The back ends are controlled by the client, and they are either in SQL Server or Oracle. There are minor differences in the names in the columns sometimes, and this is causing issues of JPA mapping. I had though of creating a view in both databases for each table, making all the names the same, which is still an option. However I was also looking at virtual or computed columns, which seem to solve the issue perfectly. Simply add a virtual column with the name I want, that reflects the name of the column I have. Then my JPA points to the name that is in both databases, and I can ignore the other one.

Some information seems to say I can create computed columns that can be updated, others seem to say that they cannot. If they can be updated, could anyone direct me as to how I do that? If they can't, does anyone have a suggestion on how I can gloss over these database differences, or is it back to creating views for me?

I have tried creating a virtual column in SQL Server and it works in terms of allowing my code to run against the two different schemas (and is much less work than creating the views) but the virtual column then can't be updated, creating a big difference in terms of what the Oracle customers can do and what the SQL Server customers can do.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for created a computed column for SQL Server?

Comment: [Specify Computed Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Pet Peeve:   Columns not Fields.

Comment: I have read the documentation - like I said in the original comment, some documentation seems to indicate it can be done, others do not. I think that some of it was referring to Microsoft Dynamic, though, even though it then said SQL Server in the main page. As this doesn't seem to be a valid route of inquiry, I guess I am looking for another option.

Comment: Using a view, which you already know about, is the way to go.

Comment: What do you mean by a computed column that can be "updated"? A computed column's value is defined by an expression; you can't `UPDATE` that value. You can `UPDATE` other columns that the expression references, which would cause that computed column's value to change as well. So you don't want to `UPDATE` the computed column's value, you need to `UPDATE` the column(s) that the computed column's value is derived from.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have virtual columns. It has computed columns, but those are not updatable (not even if you define an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, which does allow for update logic on views). A schema-bound view is the most hassle-free way to go here.

Comment: Yup, Looks like a view is the way to go. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring computed columns is as easy as defining how they should be computed.
Consider:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Quantity INT, Price DECIMAL(10,2), Total AS Price*Quantity)

INSERT INTO @Table (Quantity, Price) VALUES
(10,2),(15,4)
```

Here we create a table and define the computed column `Total` as being Price multiplied by quantity.

```
SELECT *
  FROM @Table
```

```
Quantity    Price   Total
-------------------------
10          2.00    20.00
15          4.00    60.00
```

If we want to update the value of total, since it has a defined relationship to Price and Quantity we would update those columns to indirectly affect it:

```
UPDATE @Table
   SET Price = Price/2

SELECT *
  FROM @Table
```

```
Quantity    Price   Total
-------------------------
10          1.00    10.00
15          2.00    30.00
```

You would not directly update your new, computed columns, since they just display the result of the definition you provided. If you wanted to change that definition, you'd need to alter the table and modify that definition but this will cause the entire column to be modified, not just a single row.